# What is the "maximal" size (complexity) of a DB query that is tractable in practice in your RDBMS?

Tags: database, relational-database, complexity-theory

With the growth of the size of the query, a query to a database can easily become computationally intractable by the RDBMS you use in pratice. So, I suppose, in order to use DBs in practice (do programming with a DB as a backend), you must know where the bound for the complexity/size of an admissible query is.

If you write programs that need to issue complex queries to relational databases, **what is the "maximal" size/complexity of the queries that are expected to be effectively answerable by the RDMS you use?**

And what is the usual size of the queries posed to relational database systems? How much is it lower than the maximal bound?

The motivation for asking this is [the following theoretical speculation](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-do-relational-databases-work-at-all-given-the-theoretical-exponential-comple): 
It seems to be known that to find an answer to a query *Q*
over a database *D*, one needs time *|D|<sup>|Q|</sup>*, and
one cannot get rid of the exponent *|Q|*. (Looking for a clique is an example of the worst-case query.)
As *D* can be very large in practice, we wonder why database work at all.

Comment: You said, "So, in order to use DBs in practice (do programming with a DB as a backend), you must know the bound for the complexity/size of an admissible query." I've been programming with a database on the backend for 25 years. I've never known the bound for the complexity/size of an admissible query. So it seems to be known that you're wrong about that.

Comment: @Catcall: That's also interesting that you never hit this bound, thanks! I have edited the sentence so that it sounds less strict about what kind of knowledge is supposed. (In your case: Where? Far away in my practice, never hit.) (However, my "must" should have meant just a [deductive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_mood) flavor of epistemic modality, so I just meant that given my theoretical assumptions I would infer what I said; nothing was really wrong in my sentence w.r.t. its objective truth because it was just a subjective motivation for asking.)

Comment: The typical uses of DBs seem not to be like the worst-case examples.

This may make some people believe that an RDBMS backend can be considered a working solution for their task if they can translate their problem to an SQL query (for example, [when working with Semantic Web, languages like OWL2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087275/what-is-the-maximal-size-complexity-of-a-db-query-that-is-tractable-in-practi/6099206#6099206)), although this doesn't seem to be true (you've seen the theoretical argumentation), perhaps even if the resulting query is not enormously huge.

Comment: The purpose of this question is for a non-DB-practitioner (like me) to understand what the practical limits of the current RDBMSs are, how it happens that those who work with RDBMSs don't hit these limits in their practical work, and learn more about practical tactics/workarounds that alleviate the computational complexity of query answering.

And indeed, I have learned from @Denis's answer more about the typical queries posed to DBs, and about the idea that the precise answer is not always needed, and about "genetic algorithms kicking in".

Comment: Comments at reddit: [1](http://www.reddit.com/r/Database/comments/hhei4/why_do_relational_databases_work_at_all_given_the/), [2](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/hhxcx/why_do_relational_dbs_work_for_you_in_practice_in/).

Answer (score 6):

For the note, I'd point out an issue in your question: you're assuming you'll always want a precise answer to a query. This is not the case in practice. When mining large amounts of data, an approximation of the answer will be good enough.

In the case of PostgreSQL, I'm not aware of any hard-coded limit to the number of joins, but depending on the transaction isolation level I'd expect to run out of locks long before it's reached.

Queries thrown at an RDBMS, in my experience, have a few joins at most and are written in such a way that they can use indexes. When not, the developer is usually doing something very wrong.

There arguably is the occasional report query that tends to be slower. These might involve much more complicated statements, with dozens of joins and unions and aggregates what not. But in this case a [genetic algorithm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/geqo.html) kicks in, for one. And the planner will, upon reaching [collapse limits](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-query.html), respect the join order, making it possible to write the query in an optimal way given advance knowledge on the data's repartition.

I've seem PostgreSQL swallow queries with two dozen joins without a hiccup... More typically, though, it's possible and more efficient to split such queries into smaller, bite-sized chunks; and/or to pre-aggregate some of the results it'll need.

For the row counts on large queries or data sets, running `explain` and returning the planner's estimate number of rows is usually enough: there's little point in knowing there are exactly 9,992 matching rows.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting description of the real practice!

Comment: Jasu_M [comments](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/hhxcx/why_do_relational_dbs_work_for_you_in_practice_in/c1vjaix) re "In the case of PostgreSQL, I'm not aware of any hard-coded limit to the number of joins": There is a level where the optimizer will just give up - and it's configured to 8 JOINS (or 8 tables, can't remember). And increasing this limit causes the optimizer to hit a hard-coded limit on the number of combinations (100000 or 1000000, can't remember) which results in an error message and query not being executed. (Read more there for the references to the src code.)

Comment: PostgreSQL has two optimizers. The exhaustive optimizer will give up after 8 joins, but the GEQO will continue to function. @imz's comment makes it sound like PostgrSQL has a hardcoded limit on the number of joins that are possible. That's incorrect. The depth of your query is only limited by your ability to write it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question, in my opinion. In a typical scenario, human queries seem to be small and simple (for instance, contain few cycles, if any), and RDBMSs are really efficient. Now imagine a situation where you formulate your query in a certain vocabulary available to the user, which has to be translated by a computer to the vocabulary of the relational databases (say, on the Web). This is a typical Semantic Web scenario, for which languages like OWL 2 have been designed. In this case, your original query may be small, but the resulting query, posed to an RDBMS, can be exponentially larger.

Comment: True, but then you'll usually be better of using a graph-oriented database engine such as AllegroGraph. :-)

Comment: Trouble is the data is stored in relational databases.

Comment: (@mishaz: if you reply to someone's comment, you can use his name prefixed with @ in your reply (like this: @Denis), then that user will be notified of your reply.)